# Warning when using custom segues

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios9, uistoryboardsegue

I am using SERevealViewController with swift , after I made a segue from a button on the sidebar menu to another `Viewcontroller` and set the Segue Class to the `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController` I got a warning that said

Only Custom segues support class name prior to iOS 9.0

any help to bypass this warning ?

Comment: Is your build target set to at least iOS 9?

Comment: Only way to get rid of that warning will be setting your build target to at least iOS 9. Or not using the custom class. It's really hard to silence warnings in Xcode.